# Add a class object to MSMQ, with JSON converter

Tags: c#, asp.net, msmq

Property to serialize:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ShortDateConverter))]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Logic to add to queue:

```
msMq = GetOrCreateQueue(queueName);
Message msmqMessage = new Message();
msmqMessage.Body = requestMessage;
msmqMessage.Recoverable = true;

msMq.Send(msmqMessage);
result = true;
```

`msMq.Send()` throws `invalid xml format`.

If I remove the `JsonConverter` attribute from the property its getting added to the queue without issue.

Comment: Can you post the actual error please...

Comment: Also add an example `requestMessage`